# Onclick Event Not Working For Idle Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an idle game and want something to be purchased on user click. I have an onclick event connected to it which triggers the buyCreateScript() function but it is not working. Any advice?
Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wizviper/m1ftgoyp/82/
    Javascript:

```
function buyCreateScript() {
if(bytes >= createScriptCost ) {
   createScriptAmount++;
   bytes = bytes - createScriptCost;
   createScriptCost = createScriptCost * priceIncrease;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
   <button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="createScript" 
 onclick="buyCreateScript()">Create Script-0</button>
```

Comment: it did'nt see your buyCreateScript, put your script before "onclick"

Comment: `if(bytes >= createScriptCost )`   Well bytes = 0, & createScriptCost = 10,..   `bytes >= 10` = false..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change how you load the javascript in your fiddle.

- Click on the javascript options cog icon
- Change "LOAD TYPE" to "No wrap - in < head>"
- Click "Run" and try again

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to either:

1. Keep the `onclick` attribute but add a script tag in the html section and write the function `buyCreateScript()` in it:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="createScript" onclick="buyCreateScript()">Create Script-0</button>
<script>
  function buyCreateScript() {
    console.log('works');
  }
</script>
```

2. Or, you could add an event listener in the javascript section, remove the `onclick` attribute and keep your function where it is:

```js
var createScriptBtn = document.getElementById('createScript');
createScriptBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  buyCreateScript();
});
function buyCreateScript() {
  console.log('works');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="createScript">Create Script-0</button>
```

Comment: That's a neat trick you pulled there. You posted with the answer to hold the spot, then edited it and filled in the content and explanation. Didn't know that was allowed. EDIT: Oops, wrong thread.

Comment: @spikespaz LOL. note: you can delete a comment.

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment. Once I get to a computer I will if I remember.